# shopify polaris hamburger menu

Tags: reactjs, shopify, polaris

I've been looking through shopify polaris and I noticed that in the list of icons shopify provided, there isn't the hamburger menu (unless I missed it).

However, when I look at the frame component, I can see that they use the hamburger menu in their top bar. Is it possible to use polaris in order to display the hamburger menu on its own that logs to the console once clicked?.

This is the link to the frame component:
https://polaris.shopify.com/components/structure/frame#navigation